# Error executing query in Java code to connect to Presto

Tags: jdbc, presto, trino

We are trying to connect to Presto using Java code and execute some queries. Catalog we are using is MySQL.

- Presto is installed on the Linux server. Presto CLI is working fine on Linux. Started Presto in Linux.
- MySQL is also installed on the Linux machine. We are able to access MySQL in windows using DbVisualizer.
- I created a MySQL connector catalog for Presto. I'm successful in querying data of MySQL using Presto CLI as `presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog mysql --schema tutorials`.

Executing the Java code on the Windows machine, I'm able to access MySQL and execute queries, but we are unable to query data. When we try to run a query  from Presto, it is giving us Error Executing Query. In the below example, I have used a jar from [Trinosql](https://trino.io/download.html)

```java
package testdbPresto;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PrestoJdbc {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
      
      try{ 
      //connect mysql server tutorials database here 
      Class.forName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");  
      String url = "jdbc:trino://35.173.241.37:8080/mysql/tutorials";
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("user", "root");
      properties.setProperty("password", "Redcar88!");
      properties.setProperty("SSL", "true");
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);

      Statement statement = null;  
      statement = connection.createStatement();
      //select mysql table author table two columns  
      String sql;  
      sql = "select auth_id, auth_name from mysql.tutorials.author"; 
     
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);  

      //Extract data from result set
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        //Retrieve by column name
        String name = resultSet.getString("auth_name");
        //Display values
        System.out.println("name : " + name);
      }
      //Clean-up environment
      resultSet.close();
      statement.close();
      connection.close();
      }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}  
    
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query
        at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoStatement.internalExecute(TrinoStatement.java:274)
        at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoStatement.execute(TrinoStatement.java:227)
        at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoStatement.executeQuery(TrinoStatement.java:76)
        at testdbPresto.PrestoJdbc.main(PrestoJdbc.java:29)
    Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.JsonResponse.execute(JsonResponse.java:154)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.StatementClientV1.<init>(StatementClientV1.java:110)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.StatementClientFactory.newStatementClient(StatementClientFactory.java:24)
        at io.trino.jdbc.QueryExecutor.startQuery(QueryExecutor.java:46)
        at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoConnection.startQuery(TrinoConnection.java:728)
        at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoStatement.internalExecute(TrinoStatement.java:239)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:174)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1279)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:299)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.OkHttpUtil.lambda$basicAuth$1(OkHttpUtil.java:85)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.OkHttpUtil.lambda$userAgent$0(OkHttpUtil.java:71)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.JsonResponse.execute(JsonResponse.java:131)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: Class.forName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");  

It looks like you're still loading the old PrestoDriver, though the error message is suggesting that it's using the Trino jar. 

Also you're showing your IP address in the question.

Comment: you found the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite old question but it might be still relevant.
You are trying connect to trino with presto jdbc driver. PrestoSQL was rebranded as Trino . So in order to access trino via jdb, you should use trino jdbc driver.

Add trino dependency in your classpath.
If you use maven, add this dependency in the pom.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.trino</groupId>
   <artifactId>trino-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>${trino-jdbc.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use the following driver

```
Class.forName("io.trino.jdbc.TrinoDriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works with Trino.

```
fun main() {
    val trinoUrl = "jdbc:trino://myDomain:443"
    val properties = Properties()
    properties.setProperty("user", "noUserS")
//    properties.setProperty("password", "noPass")
    properties.setProperty("SSL", "true")

    DriverManager.getConnection(trinoUrl, properties).use { trinoConn ->
        trinoConn.createStatement().use { statement ->
            statement.connection.catalog = "catalog1"
            statement.connection.schema = "default"

            println("Executing query...")

            statement.executeQuery("""
                    select 
                      restaurantId, 
                      type,
                      time 
                    from table1 
                    where time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' hour
                """.trimIndent()
            ).use { resultSet ->
                val list = mutableListOf<Map<String, String>>()

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    val data = mapOf(
                        "restaurantId" to resultSet.getString("restaurantId"),
                        "type" to resultSet.getString("type"),
                        "time" to resultSet.getString("time")
                    )
                    list.add(data)
                }

                println("Records returned: ${list.size}")
                println(list)
            }
        }
    }
    exitProcess(0)
}
```

It is Kotlin, but it's easy to understand.
The `.use {..}` it's `try-with-resources` in Java.

Hope this helps.